# Make multiselect selected elements appear outside textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

Right now I am using the jQuery plugin Chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

The multiselect option is exactly what I want to achieve, but I'd like if the selected elements appeared outside of the textbox instead of inline the others. Any quick solutions? Or should I be looking at a custom coded attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit brute but might be effective. Add your own chosen().change() event handler (as per their docs) to the texbox and simply move the `<li>` elements from the textbox to wherever you like. So something along the lines of:

```
$("#form_field").chosen().change(
    // detach from source and append to destination

);
```